# jpa mapping two properties

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I need `CompanyUser.companyRolCompanyUsers` property with `OneToMany` relation, completed in each query.

**JPA company_usr entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_usr")
public class CompanyUser extends BaseModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Company company;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usr_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean external;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CompanyRolCompanyUser> companyRolCompanyUsers;

....
```

**JPA companyRol_companyUsr entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companyRol_companyUsr")
public class CompanyRolCompanyUser extends BaseModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="companyuser_company_id",    referencedColumnName="company_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="companyuser_usr_id", referencedColumnName="usr_id")
        })
    private CompanyUser companyUser;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private CompanyRol companyRol;

....
```

How to set `mappedBy` in `companyRolCompanyUsers` property correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you want to achieve i think you need something like :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="companyUser")
private List<CompanyRolCompanyUser> companyRolCompanyUsers;
```

Comment: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.smf.model.CompanyRolCompanyUser.companyUser in com.smf.model.CompanyUser.companyRolCompanyUsers

This is the error maybe is caused by multiple @Id in CompanyRolCompanyUser entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two properties for the same column like this :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CGRADO_CODIGO", referencedColumnName = "CGRADO_CODIGO")
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private SipreGrado                  sipreGrado;

    @Column(name = "CGRADO_CODIGO",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private String                      sipreGradoCodigo;
```

Remember if you have sometimes the entity NULL you can skip it with that annotation

```
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Also,Remember to set

```
insertable=false,updatable=false
```

for the one that you dont want to include in the insert/update queries.